# Multiple Line Pattern Search and replace in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use a regular expression to do a search and replace using perl I want to insert a SQL connect statement between a JOB INPUT line and SQL OPEN line. Here are the patterns of the input

JOB INPUT NULL
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
KEY1=KEY2
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
KEY1=KEY2
KEY3=KEY3
SQL OPEN CURSOR

This has to be changed to the following

JOB INPUT NULL
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
KEY1=KEY2
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
KEY1=KEY2
KEY3=KEY3
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
SQL OPEN CURSOR

I used the following regular expression

```
( s{^(\s*job\s+input.*\n?.*?)}{$1\n$sql_connect\n}im )
```

$sql_connect has the value "SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD"

I am getting the below result

JOB INPUT NULL
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
  KEY1=KEY2
SQL OPEN CURSOR

JOB INPUT RANKEY
SQL CONNECT TO DATABASE USER USER-ID USING PAS-WD
  KEY1=KEY2
  KEY3=KEY3
SQL OPEN CURSOR

Can I do it through regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
s{^(\s*job\s+input.*?)^(\s*sql\s+open.*?\n)}{$1$sql_connect\n$2}imsg
```

It seems to work for me.